# Based on another drop down selection how to append new options to bootstrap-multiselect dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two bootstrap-multiselect dropdowns. On the selection of the first dropdown i have to bind the dropdownslist of the second dropdown.

So i am using an ajax call by sending in the first dropdowns seleted options and am succesfully getting a json object of the secodn dropdown's values.
Here is my code :

```
function FillZonesDropdown(BUId) {
    debugger
    var bu = BUId;

    bu = bu.join(",");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "@Url.Action("
        BindZonesOnBU ", "
        mycontroller ")",
        data: "{BUIds:" + bu + "}",

        success: function(Result) {
            debugger;
            var data = Result;
            $("#ddlZone").html("");

            $.each(Result, function(key, value) {
                $("#ddlZone").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Value).html(value.Text));
            });

        }

    });
}
```

But i am not seeing any change in the second dropdown's options list.

I have tried using

```
$("#ddlZone").multiselect("rebuild");
```

as suggested in one of the SO questions. But with no success.

It would be great if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
             "<option value=\"" + value.Value+ "\">" + value.Value+ "</option>"
            });
$('#ddlZone').multiselect( 'refresh' );

Comment: That did work , but with a small change.                                                                                           .                      $('#ddlZone').multiselect( 'refresh' );                                                                         $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
                $("#ddlZone").append($("<option></option>").val(value.Value).html(value.Text));
            });                                                                                                                     $("#ddlZone").multiselect("rebuild");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
        $.each(Result, function (key, value) {
            $("#ddlZone").append($("<option value="+value.Value+">"+value.Text+"</option>");
        });
$('#ddlZone').multiselect( 'refresh' );
```